# Cannot drag an image outside of card view

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

By dragging I mean changing the widget's rawX and rawY like so:

```
view.y = motionEvent.rawY - ((view.height / 2) + 120)
view.x = motionEvent.rawX - view.width / 2
```

My layout contains a card view and inside a few images that can be dragged by tapping and moving them around. The dragging works but the images disappear outside the boundaries of the card view:

[image]

(The image in the middle was dragged downwards and now it's only half visible because it's dragged outside the boundaries of the card view.)

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.android.navigation.TitleFragment">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#f2f2f2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:padding="8dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/card1"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/expense_card_image_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/expense_card_image_size"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_groceries"
                    android:src="@drawable/groceries"/>



                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/card2"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/expense_card_image_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/expense_card_image_size"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_rent"
                    android:src="@drawable/rent"/>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

What can I do to allow the images to be dragged outside of the card view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `cardView.setClipChildren(false) 
cardView.setClipToPadding(false)`  add these line in your activity / fragment and try

Comment: I added those in my fragment and unfortunately it's still not working, the images still disappear outside the card view

Comment: I don't understand why it's being downvoted I tried to elaborate as much as possible

Comment: you can't drag it outside of `CardView`, if you want to drag image in whole screen move `imageview` into top parent layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havnt seen your java code but I think you should be letting the user drag the CardView and not the ImageView inside of it. 
it is my understanding that your CardView is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. namely providing sort of a window or cutout within which the contained imageviews are visible (I have used them to make my imageviews circular for instance)

If you want the images to appear like they are inside the CardView or some other container you can place the ImageViews outside the CardView and then make them appear on top of it by using a RelativeLayout. then you can track their coordinates to see whether you consider them to fall "inside" of it or "out"

Comment: Thanks, I need the card view not to move, it's a pool of imageviews that shoudl be dragged outside of it.

Comment: Im pretty sure that goes against  the whole point of a cardview. like @Priyankagb said you cant drag them outside of their parent. Whta you can do is put them outside of the cardView but place them on top of it so it will look like they are inside this you can achieve with relative layout

Comment: Ok positioning them on top of the card and not inside it sounds like a good idea, thank you very much can I give the 50 points to your comment?

Comment: ill put the idea in the answer that way you can award them to the answer ;)

Comment: @sir-haver I edited my comment into my answer. let me know if there is anything missing

Comment: I think there should be a +50 button below the checkmark I think you have to click it or the bounty is lost. or maybe now I get it automatically I am not sure how the system works thats just what I read here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Answer (score 2):

you can't drag it outside of `CardView`, if you want to drag image in whole screen move `imageView` into top parent layout

this code will allow `imageView` to drag into whole screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.android.navigation.TitleFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/expense_card_image_size"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#f2f2f2" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/expense_card_image_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/expense_card_image_size"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_groceries"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/groceries"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/card"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/card" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/expense_card_image_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/expense_card_image_size"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_rent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/rent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/card"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/card" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks but I do need the image to be in some kind of a card view, at least something that looks like a cardview, or a box, not just on the screen

Comment: if you place image inside card view you can't drat it out of card view. A view can not move out of its parent view

Comment: I dont understand do you wnt your imageviews to disappear behind the cardview or do you want them to always be fully visible within the constraints of your screen? what is the cardview for? what does it achieve that say a relative layout does no?

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I did'nt explain myself well, I need the imageviews to NOT disappear behind the card view. The card view serves as a "pool" of images from which the user can drag imageviews outside.

Comment: @Priyankagb is there any alternative in that case that you cannot drag a widget outside of a card view? I want the parent (cardview) to serve as a container/box for the images and that they can be dragged outside of it